# Python pysftp.put raises "No such file" exception although file is uploaded

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I am using pysftp to connect to a server and upload a file.

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
self.sftp = pysftp.Connection(host=self.serverConnectionAuth['host'], port=self.serverConnectionAuth['port'],
                              username=self.serverConnectionAuth['username'], password=self.serverConnectionAuth['password'], 
                              cnopts=cnopts)
self.sftp.put(localpath=self.filepath+filename, remotepath=filename)
```

Although it works correctly most of the times, sometimes it raises the exception attached bellow. The file is read and processed by another program running on the server, so I can see that, even at these times, the file is indeed uploaded and is not corrupted.

```
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 364, in put
    confirm=confirm)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 727, in put
    return self.putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size, callback, confirm)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 689, in putfo
    s = self.stat(remotepath)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 460, in stat
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_STAT, path)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 780, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 832, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 861, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

How can I prevent this exception?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the described behaviour, I assume that the file is removed very shortly after it is uploaded by some server-side process.

By default [`pysftp.Connection.put`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.put) verifies the upload by checking a size of the target file. If the server-side processes manages to remove the file too fast, reading the file size would fail.

You can disable the post-upload check by setting `confirm` parameter to `False`:

```
self.sftp.put(localpath=self.filepath+filename, remotepath=filename, confirm=False)
```

I believe the check is redundant anyway, see
[How to perform checksums during a SFTP file transfer for data integrity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30056566/850848)

---

For a similar question about Paramiko (which pysftp uses internally), see:
[Paramiko put method throws "[Errno 2] File not found" if SFTP server has trigger to automatically move file upon upload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59621421/850848)

*And actually, you should use Paramiko directly, as pysftp is a dead project. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)*.

Answer (score 0):

Also had this issue of the file automatically getting moved before paramiko could do an `os.stat` on the uploaded file and compare the local and uploaded file sizes.

@Martin_Prikryl solution works works fine for removing the error by passing in `confirm=False` when using `sftp.put` or `sftp.putfo`

If you want this check to still run to verify the file has been uploaded fully you can run something along these lines. For this to work you will need to know the moved file location and have the ability to read the file.

```
import os

sftp.putfo(source_file_object, destination_file, confirm=False)
upload_size = sftp.stat(moved_path).st_size
local_size = os.stat(source_file_object).st_size
if upload_size != local_size:
    raise IOError(
        "size mismatch in put!  {} != {}".format(upload_size, local_size)
    )
```

Both checks use `os.stat`