# How does the confirm parameter of the paramiko put work

Tags: python, file, networking, sftp, paramiko

I noticed, that there is a parameter named confirm for the put method of the paramiko package.
I want to know how it works.
what is its function? and how to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the `SFTPClient.put` documentation](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.put):

> `confirm` (bool) – whether to do a [`stat()`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.stat) on the file afterwards to confirm the file size

If the size does not match, the `SFTPClient.put` throws `IOError` exception with *"size mismatch in put!"* message.

See also [Paramiko put method throws "[Errno 2] File not found" if SFTP server has trigger to automatically move file upon upload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59621421/850848).