# pysftp - IOError - No such file when I can see the full file on the other end

Tags: python, paramiko, ioerror, pysftp

I have a program which transfers files to different endpoints. Only one endpoint in particular fails on this conn.put():

```
try:
  conn.put(fileToPush, pushedFile)
except IOError as ioe:
    self.logPush('IOError: {} - Exiting...'.format(str(ioe)))
```

The output:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file - Exiting...

But I sftp to the destination from the command line and I do an "ls -ltr" and one of the two files I'm trying to push is there.

The file's size is 900117 bytes.
Then on sftp, I can also see the file size as 900117 bytes.

How does it transfer 1 whole file and still run into an IOError?

Comment: What about the source and destination paths for both of those files? It sounds like the second one wasn't right. You could `print(repr(fileToPush), repr(pushedFile))` to see. Do these go to the same remote directory? Does the server move files after they've been dropped in the directory?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you should use `print()` to see values in variables. You could also check current working directory `os.getcwd()` or check what you have in folder `os.listdir(...)`

Comment: See [Python pysftp.put raises "No such file" exception although file is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49718668/850848) – If this does not help, post a full exception callstack. + Example of path syntaxes + Log file of any commandline/GUI SFTP client that can upload the same file to the same target path using the same credentials.

Comment: Thank you, it was actually the same issue as the issue you linked me too. I just thought that it was different because I could see the files with an ls -ltr when I was connectin from sftp from cmd line but what I was seeing wasn't a real life listing.