# stat() check causing issues when transferring files with pysftp

Tags: python, pysftp

We have a Python process to SFTP files to various customers. A normal `put` with pysftp will also do a `stat` to confirm file size. We have one customer where we must skip this `stat` check with parameter `confirm=false`. If we do not skip this check, we receive a `{path}\{file} is not a valid path` error.

We believed this is due to the customer moving the file too quickly for the `stat` check to find it. We came to this conclusion after referencing the follow SO post:

[Python pysftp.put raises "No such file" exception although file is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718668/python-pysftp-put-raises-no-such-file-exception-although-file-is-uploaded)

In that post, the user claims that even when the `stat` check fails, the files do get transferred. Also, of course, our error messages differ. However, our customer never receives the files in these cases. This seems to mean the files never transferred in the first place. Thus, the server did not move files too quickly for `stat` check to cause a failure and something else is going on with the transfer. I'm not sure what though, as disabling `stat` check causes the transfer to succeed every time we get this issue.

What could the cause of this issue be?

Comment: That's probably not a programming problem. If `put` did not throw any exception, it means the server acknowledged the transfer. Anything that happens with the file afterwards it not your concern (as long as you delivered the file to the correct remote folder).