# Calculate hash of file with Renci SSH.NET in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, sftp, ssh.net

I'm using renci.sshnet library for upload a file on an SFTP server.

How can I calculate a hash of an uploaded file and compare with my local file? Is doable with this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here: [How to perform checksums during a SFTP file transfer for data integrity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30056566/850848).

It explains that calculation checksum for SFTP upload is hardly doable and probably not even useful.

---

If you want to do it anyway, in most cases you would have to resort to executing a shell command like `sha256sum`:

```
Dim Command = client.RunCommand("sha256sum /remote/path/test.txt")
If Command.ExitStatus <> 0 Then
    Throw New Exception(Command.Error)
End If
Dim tokens = Command.Result.Split(" ")
Dim checksum = Tokens(0)
```