# c# - vsftpd and FluentFTP - how automatic file checking with "Ftp.Gethash("FileName")

Tags: c#, hash, ftp, vsftpd, fluentftp

Programming question in C#
OS : Debian 9
FTP server : vsftpd
Dll : FluentFtp

[FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP#file-hashing) provides many methods for verify file integrity by hash without downloading it, for example:

> `GetHash()` - Gets the hash of an object on the server using the currently selected hash algorithm. Supported algorithms are available in the `HashAlgorithms` property. You should confirm that it's not equal to `FtpHashAlgorithm.NONE` (which means the server does not support the `HASH` command).`

But when I try to call:

```
Ftp.HashAlgorithms.ToString());
```

I get

> None

When I try to call:

```
Ftp.GetHash("test.exe"));
```

I get:

> FluentFTP.FtpCommandException: 'Unknown command.'

When I try to call:

```
Ftp.SetHashAlgorithm(FtpHashAlgorithm.MD5);
```

I get:

> System.NotImplementedException: 'The hash algorithm MD5 was not advertised by the server`

So, it appears that my vsftpd server doesn't support file hashing. Someone have a solutions?

Thanks,

Comment: I believe your question was incorrectly migrated from [su], as it actually belongs there. Your question is about your FTP server, not about your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vsftpd FTP server does not support **any** checksum calculation command.

---

For similar questions see:

- [FTP: copy, check integrity and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30626006/850848)
- [WinSCP: Checksum calculation (Operation not supported.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43260159/850848)

---

Common replacement for vsftpd that supports checksum calculation is [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/) (with [`mod_digest` module](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_digest.html)).