# Calculate MD5 checksum for a file after FTP upload

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, md5, ftpwebrequest

I want to perform the checksum MD5 control after the upload of file to FTP(S) server.

What steps should I follow in C#? I think I have to use the `XMD5` command on FTPS server and get the result.

But I do not know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: What FTP library/class are you using?

Comment: FtpWebResponse of .Net

Comment: Do you even know if your FTP server supports XMD5 command?

Comment: No..I'm developing and am simulating locally with filezilla server

Comment: There's no standard for checksum calculation, so there's no point developing this against some FTP server, if you are going to use another one in production.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/30626006/850848

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute random FTP commands using .NET `FtpWebRequest`, nor any other built-in .NET class.

You have to use a 3rd party FTP library for this.

---

For example WinSCP .NET assembly has [`Session.CalculateFileChecksum` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_calculatefilechecksum). The method will automatically map checksum algorithm name (as "md5") to an FTP command that the server supports. So if the server supports `XMD5`, it will use `XMD5`.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

For some background, see also my answer to:
[FTP: copy, check integrity and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30626006/850848)